MID function inside COUNTIFS
I have a column of combined date and time as text format and i want to count if some data is between to dates. so i write this:
=Countifs(DATE(MID(@Data!A:A,1,4),MID(@Data!A:A,6,2),MID(@Data!A:A,9,2)),">=A7",DATE(MID(@Data!A:A,1,4),MID(@Data!A:A,6,2),MID(@Data!A:A,9,2)),"<=A8")

@Data!A:A is where i want to convert it to date:
@Data!A:A

and then check the if;
">=A7" and "<=A8" are two cells i input custom date ranges.
but excel won't accept it and returns an error, says

There is a problem with this formula.

How to revise it? any thoughts?
Error message

I tried as above and I don't want to make extra columns for separate calculations.

Countif requires a range input. If you wrap it in MID you dereference it and becomes an array. Either do the modification in a different column and refer to that or switch to MMULT https://superuser.com/a/1814816/1856315

Yes, a different column method is much faster way to resolve it. thanks for the insight, helped a lot, cheers.

=COUNTIFS(Data!P:P,">="&Analysis!A7,Data!P:P,"<="&Analysis!A8) in which i calculated date converting in a new column. thanks again.

Better to use P1:P100 or whatever size your range is, instead of whole column referencing. It would calculate all cellsin the column, also the empty ones

@P.b how about defining a cell which i enter how many data rows is available and then the formula use this as an update to all ranges used in main formula?

You mean =COUNTIFS(Data!P1:INDEX(P:P,Q1),">="&Analysis!A7,Data!P1:INDEX(P:P,Q1)"<="&Analysis!A8) where Q1 is =MATCH(char(255),P:P) ?

I'm giving it a try and let you know the outcome, thanks so far.

The problem is that the COUNTIF* functions do not accept the dynamic arrays.
Also @ return a single value while you need to have an array to count something within.
This formula can be a solution for you:
=SUM(
  (DATE(MID(Data!A1:A10,1,4),MID(Data!A1:A10,6,2),MID(Data!A1:A10,9,2))>=A7)*
  (DATE(MID(Data!A1:A10,1,4),MID(Data!A1:A10,6,2),MID(Data!A1:A10,9,2))<=A8)
)

And A:A is not a good range to use it here. Narrow it for the data area only:
=LET(
  _r,INDIRECT("Data!A1:A"&MATCH(2,1/(Data!A:A<>""))),
  SUM(
    (DATE(MID(_r,1,4),MID(_r,6,2),MID(_r,9,2))>=A7)*
    (DATE(MID(_r,1,4),MID(_r,6,2),MID(_r,9,2))<=A8)
  )
)


Actually @A:A refers to 1 cell; the cell in column A in the current row. I think leaving out the @ is the intention, but than it's important to mention a start and end row for better performance.

this formula works without error, but it returns identical result of 1 no matter how i change the the dates interval. about selecting whole column instead of range, it is because there will be daily additions to range and i need it to auto-update itself, and it is currently able to work on non-empty cells.

@P.b @A:A refers to the cell in the same row where the formula is in. It makes the rest of calculation insignificant.

@rotabor correct row where the formula is in = current row

You can't count a single object which is returned by a formula with @. You need to exclude it. Look at Implicit intersection operator: @

@rotabor  you are right, A1:A77 resolves the issue and counting is correct relative to range, but how am i supposed to efficiently use it since, every day new rows will be added to data and does it mean I have to edit my formula every time? I might have seen VBA to solve this, but i'm not in that level.

The first solution is to convert the data range into Table and refer the named column.

@rotabor how about defining a cell which i enter how many data rows is available and then the formula use this as an update to all ranges used in main formula?

table crossed my mind too, but i want to keep the data as raw as possible, since it will grow to thousands by a year and even more. makes sense?

:-) No. It can be calculated automatically.

ok. much appreciated so far. I'll give it some trials and errors by then.

INDIRECT("Data!A1:A"&MATCH(2;1/(Data!A:A<>""))) seems to miss argument [a1]

No. Just replace the semicolon by the comma. I corrected the answer.

@rotabor with modifying it to 'Data!A2:A' (since data had header row, or i will remove header row for smoother database), and adding new data to evaluate it, it is working successfully. Thanks by the way. simply lovely job, well done.
